# Set vertex position along axis so it be equal another's position

Tags: modeling, vertices

There is a face, that consists of few vertices, and initially all of them was coplanar, so the face was parallel to the floor (*XOY*).

But I moved one vertex along *z* axis, so now face is not parallel.

How can make *z* axis value of some vertex be equal to another's vertex *z* coordinate?

[image]

Comment: you could flatten all the vertices with a SZ0 but it may deform the face, which you may not want, you could also move along Z and snap to another vertex?

Comment: @moonboots, can You describe both approaches in more details?

Comment: sure but could you show a before and after with a clear view of your mesh?

Comment: @moonboots, before and after what? Also the whole mesh is pretty large, it is plane of terrain for a game

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supose you want set the z = 1 of this 4 vertices
[image]

Scale to z=0

[image]

change z=1 in N-panel

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you've moved your vertex along Z, activate the *Snap* option (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when you'll want to snap), and choose *Snap to Vertex*:

[image]

Select the vertex, press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to move along Z, point your mouse cursor towards the vertex which you want to align with, it will snap:

[image]

Or select all, make a vertex of the coplanar faces active, choose *Active Element* in the Transform Pivot Point panel, and <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but X Y was first, and it also works